# Troubles with getting an oauth 2.0 token

Tags: python, oauth

Let me first start out by I am a noob when it comes to getting oauth tokens.  With that said, I am trying to use python version 3.11.4 and I have tested many different code configurations with no resolve.

I was hoping that the great people at stackoverflow could help me identify what I am doing wrong.

My latest code snippet is:

```
import requests


def get_access_token(url, client_id, client_secret):
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"},
        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
    )
    print(response)
    return response.json()["access_token"]


get_access_token("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://<Dynamics365_Org>.api.crm.dynamics.com", "<GUID>", "<Secret>")
```

So in the above I can see in the "print" that I get a status 200, but then I get:

"xception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
StopIteration: 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\keith\OneDrive - Microsoft\Dynamics - Growth\Application Developments\Python\Field_Service_Bulk_Oject_Creator_Via_API\FS-Bulk-Creator8.py", line 11, in get_access_token
return response.json()["access_token"]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\keith\OneDrive - Microsoft\Dynamics - Growth\Application Developments\Python\Field_Service_Bulk_Oject_Creator_Via_API\FS-Bulk-Creator8.py", line 14, in 
get_access_token("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://<Dynamics365_Org>.api.crm.dynamics.com", "", "")
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)"

So with that I am not sure what to test / do next...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Currently I am just trying to get an oauth token so that I can then use the token with other get or post request downstream.

Comment: just check in response how the data is coming